# C++ : Does char pointer to std::string conversion copy the content?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, stdstring

When I convert a `char*` to `std::string` using the constructor:

```
char *ps = "Hello";
std::string str(ps);
```

I know that std containers tend to copy values when they are asked to store them. 
Is the whole string copied or the pointer only?
if afterwards I do `str = "Bye"` will that change ps to be pointing to "Bye"?

Comment: they have assignment operators overloaded and actually if i am guessing correctly they would use copy and swap algorithm. and a temporary string object will be created from char*.

Comment: @Koushik: you're guessing wrong. Making a shallow copy here would be counterintuitive and prone to errors.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe yes i realise the pointer is not copied and there is a deep copy and there should be an internal buffer to hold this.

Comment: Don't assign string literals to `char*`, always use `const char*`. String literals are not supposed to change.

Comment: `char *ps = "Hello";` should be `const char *ps = "Hello";`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`std::string` object will allocate internal buffer and will copy the string pointed to by `ps` there. Changes to that string will not be reflected to the `ps` buffer, and vice versa. It's called "deep copy". If only the pointer itself was copied and not the memory contents, it would be called "shallow copy".

To reiterate: `std::string` performs deep copy in this case.

Comment: Can you add a source for that?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig The Standard (N4140, §21.4-2) says *The member functions of `basic_string` use an object of the `Allocator` class passed as a template parameter
to allocate and free storage for the contained char-like objects.*

Answer (score 5):

`str` will contain a copy of `ps`, changing `str` will not change `ps`.