# How to copy a char into a char* vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, dirent.h

I am using dirent to read filenames from a specific folder, and I want to save the names in a char* vector. It seems that it's copying some weird symbols instead of copying the filenames. This is what I tried so far:

```
std::vector<char*> filenames;

int filenamesAndNumberOfFiles(char *dir)
{
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *fd;
    int count = 0;

    if ((fd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "listdir: can't open %s\n", dir);
        return 0;
    }
    while ((dp = readdir(fd)) != NULL) 
    {
        if (!strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
            continue;    /* skip self and parent */
        printf("Filename: %s\n", dp->d_name);
        filenames.push_back(dp->d_name);
        count++;
    }
    closedir(fd);
    return count;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't copy the filenames and how could I do to copy them?

**Edit:**
d_name is a char variable declared as:

```
char d_name[PATH_MAX];
```

and it seems like in my program PATH_MAX is equal to 260.

PS: It is my first time when I use dirent, so I am not really familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user2079303 said a second call to readdir will overwrite the results returned by the first call ([link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html)).

But I would recommend you to use a string for this in C++:

```
std::vector<std::string> filenames;

int filenamesAndNumberOfFiles(char *dir)
{
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *fd;
    int count = 0;

    if ((fd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "listdir: can't open %s\n", dir);
        return 0;
    }
    while ((dp = readdir(fd)) != NULL) 
    {
        if (!strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
            continue;    /* skip self and parent */
        printf("Filename: %s\n", dp->d_name);
        filenames.push_back( std::string(dp->d_name) );
        count++;
    }
    closedir(fd);
    return count;
}
```

You can always use `c_str()` if you need a `char*` later on.

Comment: As I commented on Simple's answer, the reason why you claim the string becomes invalid is wrong. `dp` is just a pointer and it going out of scope has no effect on the string.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `std::vector<char*>` with `std::vector<std::string>`. And add `#include <string>`. That should solve the problem.

It seems that you haven't yet grasped the concept of pointers and arrays in C/C++, and I'm not sure if explaining that fits within the limits of an SO answer. But this answer might be of use: [C++ : Does char pointer to std::string conversion copy the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439430/c-does-char-pointer-to-stdstring-conversion-copy-the-content/16439516#16439516)

In short, the problem with your code is that instead of copying the memory where string is stored (the characters themselves, `char[PATH_MAX]`), you were only copying a pointer to that memory (`char*`). And the memory block pointed to was later reused or even deleted, leaving your stored pointer invalid.

Comment: Or he can put at the top of the file `using namespace std;` and then write `vector<string>`

Comment: @Alex No, you don't : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Alex: Or he can better avoid it.

Comment: Ok ok wow ! I just learnt something. I just tried to help but as C is not my main language at all, I didn't know it could be wrong to use namespace

Comment: It's ok to use namespace, but when you use strings you should declare them as `std::string` otherwise it can became ambiguous.

Comment: @Alex sorry if I am too pedantic, but C is not C++, and this question is about C++. C does not even have namespaces.

Comment: @user2079303 ok well :) it's always a good thing to spread the word ! And to learn the good things

Answer (score 3):

You need to store copies of the string. Use `vector<string>`. When you `push_back(dp->d_name)` you are storing a dangling pointer, because `dp` goes out of scope after the function ends.

Comment: Put some code for him and this will be the best answer.

Comment: `dp` going out of scope does not cause the char pointer to dangle. The problem is calling `readdir` repeatedly which causes the previous string to be freed and therefore leaves the pointer dangling. The solution is correct, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you push a pointer, `dp->d_name` onto the vector, however the string this pointer points to is gone when you call the next `readdir()` call.

Instead, you must make a copy of that string, and push it onto the vector:

```
filenames.push_back(strdup(dp->d_name));
```

Now, you must remember to free() this string that is copied into the vector when you are done with your `filenames` vector

However, please don't do this at all. Just use:

```
std::vector<std::string> filenames;
```

And you can use your original code here, and the memory management will be taken care of.